# C call function from another source file

Tags: c, function, header

Here is my code:

**main.c**

```
#include <bluetooth.h>
#include <tftController.h>
main() {
initLCD();
wait();
}
```

**bluetooth.c**

```
#include "bluetooth.h"
void mainHandler() {
    if (receieve == "start") {
    startTFT();
    }
}
```

**tftController.c**

```
void startTFT() {
     sw(0x51);
     delay(100);
     sw(0x08);
     delay(100);
     putImage();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `startTFT()`does not get called from **bluetooth.c** even though the code compiles nicely. anyone can help me up or point what's wrong here ? Really appreciated !!! I'm using this on a microcontroller to drive a TFT LCD.

Comment: Where is `mainHandler` called?

Comment: Where is 'receive' defined? Comparing it to '"start"' using '==' is probably not what you want

Comment: mainHandler will be called when ever an interrupt occurs .It does get called automatically. I did not include all the code but mainly receive is a string that has the data received from the Bluetooth line.  Once all data collected it jumps to the code I included there

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mainHandler`:

**main.c**

```
#include <bluetooth.h>
#include <tftController.h>
main() {
    initLCD();
    mainHandler();
    wait();
}
```

Comment: I think I did not explain well, mainHandler is an interrupt handler function, it will get called automatically whenever there is data coming through the bluetooth line.